# Database credential rotation with prisma

Tags: prisma

I have an Express server that uses Prisma with an AWS Aurora Postgres backend.  Does anyone know how I might allow for database credential rotation without having any server downtime?

I've set up a mechanism where the server reads the database credentials from AWS Secrets Manager at start up.  I can update the secret whenever the credentials are rotated, but I'm not sure how I would then force the app to reread the credentials upon authentication failure.

Comment: I think you would need to setup a health check function in middleware that tries to connect to the database and in case the authentication fails, it fetches the new credentials and then passes this new credentials to Prisma Client.

Comment: Let me know if you would like me to share a code sample

Comment: The issue with using a health check function is that any operations that fail prior to credential refresh will need to be retried.  Instead, I was hoping for some sort of hook that I could add the retry mechanism into.  I ended up implementing a solution which is documented in my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping the calls to Prisma in a function that retries an operation in case of authentication failure.

```
export async function executeSql<T, R>(dataSource: PrismaDataSource<T>, func:() => Promise<R>): Promise<R> {
    try {
        return await func();
    } catch (err) {
        const errorMessage = (err as Error).message;
        if (errorMessage.includes(DATABASE_AUTH_ERROR_TXT)) {
            Logger.warn("Operation failed because of invalid credentials");
            if (dataSource.isClientRefreshable()) {
                Logger.warn("Getting credentials and retrying...");
                // refresh the credentials and try the operation again
                await dataSource.refreshClient();
                return await func();
            }
        }
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Call like so where `this._client` is a wrapper around the PrismaClient ...

```
return executeSql(this._client, async () => {
    const entity = await this._client.getClient().application.findUniqueOrThrow({
        where: {
            id: applicationId,
        },
    });

    // Do other stuff

    return entity;
});
```

If there is a better way to do this, I'd be happy to know.